# Not able to view existing H2 database using H2 console

Tags: java, database, h2

I am new to H2 database. I had installed H2 console. I am trying to connect existing H2 schema which is created via my java application using below Url.

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:./mydb;INIT=create schema IF NOT EXISTS datamagic;AUTO_SERVER=true</property>
    <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password@1</property>        
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">mydb</property>
```

Above configuration is creation mydb.mv.db file on my disc.

Now I am having below dilemma.

I would like to access above database using H2 console. I have tried couple of options but everytime it is creating new database e.g. mydb.h2.db.  I had used below

```
jdbc:h2:file:<mydir_pathof_mv_db_file>\mydb
```

I am sure that something silly is missing.Does anyone help me to resolve this issue. It is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect a H2 database started by an application. You have to start the server.
The [official document](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server) offer the steps to start a **TCP server** and connect the TCP server.

For web application, you can also config [H2 Console Servlet](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#web_applications). The servlet allow you access the database via web browser. The detail steps are under section *Using the H2 Console Servlet*.